# Vertically align a div that is already horizontally centered

Tags: html, css

I tried to vertically a div that contains a 3 divs using [this](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) as a reference.
However, I was not able to achieve it using `disply: flex` and other things mentioned in the reference.
The problem is the entire div with `id="content"` gets only horizontally centered and not vertically centered. I am looking to center it vertically as well. How shall I proceed?

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/428zo4wq/) on it.

Here is what I've tried so far.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="c-left">
            <video width="400">
              <source src="https://d31vcf9x8qnwak.cloudfront.net/videos/encoded/DuLzrFlrH.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="c-r-top">
            blah blah
        </div>
        <div class="c-r-rest">
            blah blah
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
width: 1170px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
overflow: auto;
}
#content{
width: 100%;
}
#content .content-wrapper{
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this 
**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/428zo4wq/1/)**

```css
.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

video {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your classes:

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. Also, this approach doesn't use display: flex

Comment: Changed it. I think it probably is centred, but without the height being specified, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. It's not pretty if the page is too small though so you might want some media queries in there.

```css
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#content .content-wrapper {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="c-left">
        <video width="400">
          <source src="https://d31vcf9x8qnwak.cloudfront.net/videos/encoded/DuLzrFlrH.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class="c-r-top">
        blah blah
      </div>
      <div class="c-r-rest">
        blah blah
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `#content` a set height and make it `display:flex` with `align-items:center`

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/KVNqXz)

Code:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to W3:
Source: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html
About half-way down the page, they suggest using

```
display:flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

on a parent container.